How to login FTP account in windows explorer address bar directly when password contains "@" symbol?
I am trying to login my FTP account directly in windows file explorer address bar including password pre-typed. It works fine when ftp URL is,
ftp://username:password@hostname
unfortunately, my FTP account password contains @ symbol, hence not working in address bar.
example: ftp://username:password@123@hostname
here password@123 is my password, as it takes everything after @ symbol as hostname, it considering my password end part as hostname like 123@hostname as hostname
I can setup like typing without password at address bar by following method,

type this in address bar: ftp://username@hostname (without password)
then press enter, a wizard open and type password there.
this method works, but for this need to type password every time.
but my actual need is, login with password in address bar itself.

ftp://username:password@hostname Like this when password does not contain the symbol @ also it works. But I don't want to change my password, as it used in other system and projects too.
So, is there any workaround to directly use the full ftp URL in address bar with password (when password contains @ symbol in it)?
Additionally, tried URL encoding too at password, but it leads to invalid password. (tried %40 instead of @ symbol, no use.)

Are you really set on using the file explorer FTP? I believe this task would be much easier when using command prompt or Powershell.

I dont know how to escape characters like that, but you could alternatively map the FTP as a network drive. In file explorer, right click on This PC, chose map network drive. You can also right click This PC and chose Add a network location to add it as a network location. Both options require you to fill in your credentials and they will be saved.

I have just tried to replicate the issue with a simple RFC compliant ftp server obtained with
python3 -m pyftpdlib -p 21 -w --user=testusr --password=test@ta1
and  placing the following URL
`ftp://testusr:test%40ta1@127.0.0.1/`

in the "address bar" of explorer.exe
is working just fine, so
if  %40 is fine to specify the @ charater in the password,
I would be tempted to assume that the issue is somewhere else ( in the ftp server ?)

@sigmud After seeing your comment, I wonder and retried, Still same issue. Can you please try with my password which is Test@000 As I use this password %40 continuously with 000 (example : Test%40000 So, can you please confirm this password works. Whatever times I try same error. I doubt that %40+000

ok, I entered the URL
ftp://testusr:Test%40000@127.0.0.1/
in explorer.exe and it worked
then, to be on the safe side,  I stopped and restarted the ftp server with a slightly different user and password
testZZZ:Test%40012
and, after changing the URL accordingly, it still worked fine as before.
Maybe you can install wireshark to sniff the connection (after all ftp traffic is in clear), so you can detect if the problem is really on the ftp server...
